# iOS App compiles and runs, just shows black screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

Here's the rundown:

- The project build successfully
- When ran on XS Max simulator: the app shows the launch screen however, it shows only black after that with no run-time errors.
- When ran on any other simulator: the app shows the launch screen however, the app shows black but the console reads..

> libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not
>   supported on this platform

.

I've updated the app from Swift 2 to 4.2. Most of the error fixes were just updating syntax.

Any insight that would help solve this would be appreciated!

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: Any]?) -> Bool {
    setConstants()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.rootViewController = RootViewController.sharedInstance
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    preloadKeyboard()

    return true
}
```

RootViewController's Shared Instance:

```
static let sharedInstance = RootViewController(nibName: "RootViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Why this is not a duplicate question:

- The MGc90 is not the main error I'm trying to resolve (the black screen is)
- Solutions from the link question do not fix the situation
- Sol#1 Xcode 9.4.1 yields the same error
- Sol#2 Removing private from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions only yields an error
- Sol#3 Gives good insight on what that error means and helps me understand why it's not showing an error on XS Max
- Sol#4 I don't have a breakpoint or an alert to continue
- Sol#5 I have no ambiguous layout warnings
- Sol#6 Deployment target is just fine
- Sol#7 I know the newer iPhone model doesn't yield the error but still shows black screen
- Sol#8 Fonts are loaded
- Sol#9 Another change simulator.

Comment: Can you show the code for your AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method?

Comment: @AshleyMills I added the requested method

Comment: Can you show the code for the `sharedInstance` in `RootViewController`?

Comment: @Swinny89 That code has been added, as per your request :)

Comment: Do a google search for the console message: `libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform` ... you'll find a bunch of results... see if any of those discussions answer your question.

Comment: @DonMag I did check a lot of those.. Sadly, most say to run the simulator on XS Max (which is why I included that info on the question) the rest are not iOS based. If you have a link that you think would be helpful, please share :)

Comment: @AshleyMills could you remove the mark stating that this is a duplicate question?

Comment: This normally happens when the rootViewController on window is nil. I'd suggest using a breakpoint to ensure that it's not nil, if so, you can then debug your method that creates the viewcontroller to see why it is

Comment: Where is the nib located? Is it a xib or a storyboard? Are you sure you haven't misspelled nib file name? Have you tried `RootViewController(nibName: "RootViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)`?

Comment: @mag_zbc RootViewController.xib is located in the same group as RootViewController.swift. Also yes I have tried Bundle.main